# Refund with extra shipping costs via API

Tags: shipping, invoice, refund

We have a webshop for shoes, and if shoes, which are in the sale, are send back we want to charge the customer with extra shipping costs. (5 euro)

Now I use the POST V1/invoice/:invoiceId/refund

Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Gr, Peter

Answer (score 0):

Change the JSON format of the API request.

Have a look at this example,

```
{
  "invoiceId": "12345",  
  "refundAmount": 45,  // Original purchase amount
  "shippingCost": 5    // Additional shipping cost for returned shoes on sale
}
```